# Convert int to byte as HEX in C#

Tags: c#, hex, int, byte

I need to send a Hex string over the serial to a device, I do that now like this:

```
byte[] c = new byte[3];
c[0] = 0x57;
c[1] = 0x30;
ComPort.Write(c,0,c.Length );
```

Now I need to convert a value of int like 30 to `c[1] = 0x30` or a int value of 34 gives `c[1] = 0x34`.
I hope you see what I mean.

So how can I mange this?

Comment: What will you do if the value is `100`?

Comment: the values are just between 30 and 39

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you try to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Is there another way to send a HEX command by serial port I just found that I can do that over the 'byte[] c = new byte[3]' and afterwards with ComPort.Write(c,0,c.Length );

Comment: You should rather change your input to e.g. 48 than 30 so you get 0x30 from it.

Comment: What happened to byte `c[2]`? Is is intentional that it remains zero?

Comment: missed c[2] it is also a value, however can I change the code to:(byte)(48) and this should give me 0x30???

Comment: @user1235288 Yes, `(byte)48` is the same as its hex representation `(byte)0x30`.

Comment: nice it does work that way! thx a lot!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This format is called [*binary-coded decimal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). For two-digit numbers, integer-divide by ten and multiply by sixteen, then add back the remainder of the division by ten:

```
int num = 45;
int bcdNum = 16*(num/10)+(num%10);
```

Comment: @user1235288 Yes, (byte)48 is the same as its hex representation (byte)0x30.

Comment: A struct `UInt4` or `nibble` could have made this more intuitive. Then one could have `new nibble[6]` instead of `new byte[3]` and then use `0x4` together with `0x5` instead of `0x45`.

Comment: what it will be for n digit number that can be contained by int?I mean any number to be expressed as 2 byte Hex numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this could be

```
c[1] = Convert.ToByte(num.ToString(), 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose int Data=2821; was to send over COM Port:

```
c[0]= Convert.ToByte(data & 0x00FF); 

c[0]= Convert.ToByte(data & 0xFF00) >> 8);

ComPort.Write(c,0,c.Length );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 1366;
string bcdNum = num.ToString("X");
if (bcdNum.Length < 2)
bcdNum = "0" + bcdNum;
byte[] bytes_str=Enumerable.Range(0, bcdNum.Length).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(bcdNum.Substring(x, 2), 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?