# C# - Convert Int to Hex 4 Bytes

Tags: c#, hex

I want to convert an int to hex 4 bytes.

I use this :

```
int a = 50;
a.ToString("X8");
```

This return "00000032".

But i want to return "0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x32".

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794146/convert-int-to-byte-as-hex-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
int a = 50;

string result = string.Join(", ", BitConverter.GetBytes(a).Reverse().Select(b => "0x" + b.ToString("X2")));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: this is a very bad idea in the general case; it assumes endianness; it is also pretty inefficient; there are much better ways today

Comment: @MarcGravell Going by the YAGNI principle. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson aye, in some sense it depends on the target, but: when you're dealing with primitives vs bytes, IMO endianness is more of a "you really really are going to need it, but many people don't know that they do" - "YRRAGTNIBMPDKTTD" :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an area where you need to be very careful about "endianness"; in most simple scenarios, your best bet is to use shift operations, i.e.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    static string ByteHex(int value) => (value & 0xFF).ToString("X2");
    int a = 50;
    Console.WriteLine("0x" + ByteHex(a >> 24));
    Console.WriteLine("0x" + ByteHex(a >> 16));
    Console.WriteLine("0x" + ByteHex(a >> 8));
    Console.WriteLine("0x" + ByteHex(a));
}
```

In more nuanced cases, there is a new-ish `BinaryPrimitives` type that is your friend:

```cs
int a = 50;
Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[4];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(span, a);
// now access span[0] - span[3]
```

This is usually preferable to `BitConverter` which a: is allocation-heavy, and b: is awkward re endianness (you need to flip on `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`)